# Bug in pst-circ: arrows dont work properly for \coil[dipolestyle=elektor]

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

in pst-circ the 'arrows' parameter is used for electrical connections. There is a problem for inductances with `\coil[dipolestyle=elektor]`, where the 'arrows' parameter also affects the inner lines:
[image]
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,3)
\pnode(0,0){P00}
\pnode(0,2){P02}
\coil[dipolestyle=elektor,arrows=o-*](P00)(P02){$L_1$}
\nput{270}{P00}{arrows=o-\textasteriskcentered}
\pnode(3,0){P30}
\pnode(3,2){P32}
\coil[dipolestyle=elektor,arrows=*-o](P30)(P32){$L_2$}
\nput{270}{P30}{arrows=\textasteriskcentered-o}
\pnode(6,0){P60}
\pnode(6,2){P62}
\coil[dipolestyle=elektor,arrows=-](P60)(P62){$L_3$}
\nput{270}{P60}{arrows=-}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will be fixed in next update, available in one or two days or from here:
http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-circ/

[image]